# Preparing Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

[image]
 -

I have a tabular data with values as in picture. I created a pivot table in excel 2007 .How can I get count value of each up/Down for date specified. I tried to by making one column row and other as values but it would not work.

The result would be:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to use a countif function on a second tab. something like

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"UP")
```

and

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,"DOWN")
```

and copy it across the range of dates.

If you can format your data differently to look like this

[image: Data]

Then the pivot table becomes easy withthe following settings

[image: pivot setup]

Comment: I used this already and +1 for this :) But It would be easier if I could use make a pivot table somehow :) :D

Comment: if it is possible to reformat your data you will be able to pivot table... otherwise it will be difficult. Can the data take the form Date|Status|Qty? If so then a simple pivot table is possible.... if not formulas are the path of least resistance

Comment: Qty is the one that I need to compute :)

Comment: Sorry it is really just two columns Data|Status

Comment: Can you please give me any example pls :)

Comment: I've added what the solution would look like if you are able to reformat your data